# How to show a popup when the checkbox is ticked in Magento using ajax

Tags: ajax, popup, checkbox

Just needed to add a popup modal when the checkbox is ticked and post the values to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code which open the popup modal on the view button click you can change it according to your checkbox.

```
<div id="modal" >
    <div class="modal-body-content">
    Pop up Stuff
    </div>
</div>

<button id="button">
    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View')) ?></span>
</button>

    <script>
        require([
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ], function($, modal) {

            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                title: 'Pop Up Title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function() {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
    
            var popup = modal(options, $('#modal'));
            $("#button").click(function() {
                $('#modal').modal('openModal');
            });
        });
    </script>
```